# Efeito slideUp/slideUp do jquery não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Boa tarde a todos, eu estou criando uma galeria em um site mas tem um efeito em slideDown quando clica na imagem que desce uma div que tem uma foto maior e uma descrição. Quando clico em outra foto fecha a div em slideUp.

Eu consegui aplicar o efeito slideUp quando fecha a div no "X", mas não estou conseguindo aplicar os efeitos slideUp/slideUp quando troca a foto, somente um efeito de aparecer a div.

Coloquei no jsfiddle todas as minhas tentativas no o jquery.

Obrigado a todos.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luisfernandomangia/jLLdowys/)

Comment: Poderia alterar a linha "$(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block");" para "$(this).find("+ div.info").slideDown("fast");", mas dessa forma o efeito ocorreria SEMPRE que clicasse em uma imagem. Quer que o efeito ocorra sempre, ou apenas no primeiro clique?

Comment: isso mesmo Thiago Barros. Só uma coisinha que agora que percebi. Quando clica de imagem, a div tem que fechar com slideUp e abrir com slideDown com os outro dados. E quando clicar na mesma imagem, tem que fechar a div.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.item").click(function() {

    $("div.info").css("display", "none");
    $(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block").hide().slideDown();
  });
  $(".fechar").click(function() {
    $(".info").slideUp("400");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.fechar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.item {
  background-color: blue;
  border: red 5px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

div.info {
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/500">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/501">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/502">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/503">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/504">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/507">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/508">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/509">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/510">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200/?random" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/511">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <h3>SHOPPING DA GÁVEA</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque tempus mollis. Nunc ut imperdiet arcu. Sed sagittis dui non faucibus ultricies. Maecenas et dui non neque elementum varius nec et massa. Cras nec rhoncus leo. Duis nec
          iaculis magna. Sed imperdiet, arcu ut imperdiet pharetra, quam enim lobortis felis, nec sagittis massa sem scelerisque nibh.</p>
      </div>

    </div>


    <span class="fechar">x</span>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Só alterar essa parte: `$(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block");` para `$(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block").hide().slideDown();`

**Edit de acordo com comentário:**

Substitua essa parte:

```
$("div.info").css("display", "none");
$(this).find("+ div.info").css("display", "block").hide().slideDown();
```

por:

```
    $("div.info").each(function() {
        if (! $(this).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
          $(this).slideUp();
        }
    });

    if ( $(this).find("+ div.info").is( ":hidden" ) ) {
      $(this).find("+ div.info").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).find("+ div.info").slideUp();
    }
```

Comment: Ou alterar a linha para "$(this).find("+ div.info").slideDown("fast");", como mencionei, mas o efeito sempre ocorrerá (como no seu exemplo), e o usuário - ainda - não disse como imagina o resultado.

Comment: isso mesmo Jessica. Só uma coisinha que agora que percebi. Quando clica de imagem, a div tem que fechar com slideUp e abrir com slideDown com os outro dados. E quando clicar na mesma imagem, tem que fechar a div

Comment: Atualizei, dá uma olhada!

Comment: Obrigado Jessica, desculpe a demora, estive em repouso. É quase isso mesmo, no caso é aparecido com este link http://animasom.com.br/, que quando clica a div sobe e desce.